# Session Vars in database search error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I have a simple login for my site.
When they login , a session variable is created

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $myemail;
```

On another page, i want to
search  through the database where email = the users email

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM work where Email = '.$_SESSION['Susername'].'  ";
```

I am getting an error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) on that line

Also Subline Text 2 is highlighting the username in purple if that is any help
![enter image description here][1]

Can somebody spot some syntax error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you're trying to concatenate with `.` without actually exiting the current "double quotes", single quotes don't exit into "normal space" from within a double-quoted string.

Also, you should quote the value going into the SQL statement. Then, you should either have:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM work where Email = '{$_SESSION['username']}'";
```

Or otherwise:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM work where Email = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";
```

Comment: You're welcome @BarryBurke. I prefer the first approach. I find it much more readable than constantly jumping in and out of quotes, gives my eyes a headache.